# What are the different Spanish words for "Black Eyed Peas"?

Tags: traducción, comida

Growing up my Grandfather would ask my Mother to cook some black eyed peas for good luck in the New Year.  I'm having trouble remembering the Spanish word that he would use. What could it be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is “pea” translated into Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23951/how-is-pea-translated-into-spanish)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in wikipedia [1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alubia_carilla), I think that the best translation is "alubias carilla". In this link you have more information [alubias recipe](https://alimentarte.net/alubias-carilla-con-calabaza-y-tomate/)

Comment: Esto debe ser específico de alguna región. En Colombia nunca he oído de "alubias". *Peas* en Colombia son Alverja o, Arveja

Comment: En España no he oído nunca Arveja/Alverja, pero "peas" son "guisantes". Las "alubias" también se llaman "frijoles" y en otras regiones de España, judias, habas, habichuelas o fabes

Comment: An internet image search for alubia carilla shows what are clearly black-eyed peas as I know them so this is the correct answer for at least some parts of the hispanophone world.

Answer (score 0):

It will depends on what Spanish region you were living, because for the common food (like the peas), every region can have his own name.

Usually you can translate "Peas" as "Guisantes". But, there are more similar legumes that could be 'Peas'. It's the same with the word "Nuts" that can refer to: Almendras, Nueces, Avellanas, etc...

As I don't know any "Black Guisante" (they are greens), I can suppose that the word was: "Habichuelas"

[image]

Comment: Whatever your picture shows they are definitely not black-eyed peas. The clue is in the name, black-eyed peas have a black spot at one end and are slightly rounder than what you show.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware about the clue in the name :)